# PHP echoes 2015-06-00 as '31st' after query

Tags: php

In my database I have a row named game_release and it's a date field.

Games that have no specific release date yet (for example we know it's going to be released in June) are entered with 00, such as 2015-06-00. That works, and if my query includes 00, everything's fine, but...

Instead of showing Day as 0, it's being echoed as 31. I have no idea why, and apparently PHP has trouble with incomplete dates.

This is my code:

```
                    <?php

                    $platform_id = 7;
                    $query="SELECT * FROM game WHERE game_id IN (SELECT game_id FROM game_platform WHERE platform_id=".$platform_id.") AND game_release BETWEEN '2015-12-01' AND '2015-12-31' ORDER BY game_release";

                    $result=mysqli_query($link,$query) or die (mysqli_error());
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                    {

                            echo"<table border=1>
                            <tr>
                                <th width=40px>Day</th>
                                <th width=270px>Title</th>
                                <th width=203px>Genre</th>
                                <th width=203px>Developer</th>
                                <th width=205px>Publisher</th>
                                <th width=61px>Retail?</th>
                                <th width=30px height=30px></th>
                                <th width=104px>Note</th>
                            </tr>";

                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                           {
                            echo"
                            <tr>
                                <td> ". (new DateTime($row['game_release']))->format("j") ." </td>
                                <td>{$row['game_name']}</td>

                                <td>";
                                $query="SELECT * FROM genre WHERE genre_id=".$row['game_genre']; 
                                $genreresult=mysqli_query($link,$query);                                    $genrerow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($genreresult);
                            echo $genrerow['genre_name'];
                            echo "</td>
                                <td>{$row['game_dev']}</td>
                                <td>{$row['game_pub']}</td>
                                <td>{$row['game_type']}</td>
                                <td><a href=\"{$row['game_site']}\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"images/officialwebsite.png\" title=\"Official website\"/></a>
                                    <a href=\"{$row['game_trailer']}\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"images/youtube.png\" title=\"Trailer\"/></a></td>
                                <td>{$row['game_note']}</td>
                            </tr>";


                           }

                           echo"</table>";
                           }

                            else
                            {
                            echo "There don't seem to be any confirmed nor rumoured releases this month!";
                            }
                    ?>
```

This code generates the day:

```
<td> ". (new DateTime($row['game_release']))->format("j") ." </td>
```

What can I do to have 00 echoed as 00, or do you guys know another way to clearly indicate that the dates is incomplete? I still want it to be echoed to the table showing that month's releases of course.

Comment: Invalid == incomplete. Crap in, crap out. Give PHP *real* values and it will be a very happy camper.

Comment: Hey John. In my defense: I meant incomplete related to the context I'm working with. I realize the dates are invalid for PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the date is technical an invalid date. So you can do a simple check with [`checkdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) if the date is valid and if not display `00` like this:

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $row['game_release']);
if (checkdate($month, $day, $year)) {
    echo "<td> ". (new DateTime($row['game_release']))->format("j") ." </td>";
} else {
    echo "<td>00</td>";
}
```

So your code should look something like this:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $row['game_release']);
    if (checkdate($month, $day, $year)) {
        $date = (new DateTime($row['game_release']))->format("j");
    } else {
        $date = "00";
    }

    echo"<tr>
            <td> ". $date ." </td>
            <td>{$row['game_name']}</td>
        <td>";
    //...
```

Comment: Hey, this works perfectly! I had no idea where to start. Thank you so much!